# How can I check if mysql is installed using a bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, osx, mysql

I need to check if mysql is installed from within a bash script. What would be an efficient way of doing that? I thought I could do this:

```
if [ ! -f `which mysql` ] ; then
    echo "foo" 
fi
```

But I think I might be confused about something. What would be a better solution? It should be portable and work on both `Ubuntu` and `OSX`.

Comment: What exactly confuses you about the code you posted? What did you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: `which` only returns regular files anyway. This test will always be false.

Comment: @kopischke I expected `which mysql` to give back the path to mysql that then is checked if it's a file or not. But it seems to just not work.

Comment: This will also potentially break in any shell where `[` is an external command, as if `which` does not return anything, `-f` will be missing an argument.

Comment: Also, using which will fail if mysql is an alias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type mysql >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "MySQL present." || echo "MySQL not present."
```

Comment: What is the problem with searching only in `$PATH`?  If it is installed in a non-standard location you need to know that location to run it anyway.  And if you know the non-standard location it probably doesn't make much sense to run a script that checks if it is installed or not.

Comment: @Bram Being installed does not implicitly mean it's going to be in a standard location. What if, as root, I want to know how many mysqld binaries users have compiled and installed on the system? It could be in /opt (not usually considered standard), could be under some user /home directory, could be in a subdirectory under /usr/local. There could also be multiple versions of mysqld installed. Assuming the binary is going to be in $PATH or it's irrelevant is not, in my opinion, a good view to have.

Comment: @Bram - I have absolutely no idea. I'm just providing an alternative for uther's answer.

Comment: I do not recommend running `find` over the entire filesystem. It's rude. You may be traversing external drives, network mounts, … If `mysql` isn't in the path, it might as well not be installed. There might be a non-working installation of mysql that's not in the path on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you exclusively use your Ubuntu package manager for MySQL installation, then you can just use the dpkg front-end to dpkg-query to find out whether the package is installed.

```
# Look up package with dpkg-query.
if dpkg --list mysql-client | egrep -q ^ii; then
    :
fi
```

This is fast and reliable, but obviously only works when you use your Ubuntu system packages.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Rightscale script and needed to know if mysql-server was installed. I used:

```
if [ -f /etc/init.d/mysql* ]; then
    echo "installed"
else 
    echo "not installed"
fi
```